# java.lang.Object cannot be cast

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to get all user votes for messages in custom question:

```
List<Vote> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Vote as v left join v.message as m " +
                "where m.question=:question and v.user=:user and v.voteType=:voteType")
        .setParameter("question", question)
        .setParameter("user", user)
        .setParameter("voteType", VoteType.MESSAGE)
        .list();
System.out.println(list.get(0).getMessage().getNumber());
```

And got exception in the last string:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   ru.kapahgaiii.qa.domain.Vote
>     ru.kapahgaiii.qa.repository.ChatDAOImpl.getVotes(ChatDAOImpl.java:114)

What am I doing wrong?

Vote.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "votes")
public class Vote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "vote_id")
    private Integer voteId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "vote_type", length = 8)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VoteType voteType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private Message message;
```

Comment: Can you check with a debugger if `list` really contains `Vote` objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing wrong cast. Hibernate returns you all objects from the query as you requested. But you needed to use `Vote` object, which is at index 0.

```
List<Object[]> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Vote as v left join v.message as m " +
                "where m.question=:question and v.user=:user and v.voteType=:voteType")
        .setParameter("question", question)
        .setParameter("user", user)
        .setParameter("voteType", VoteType.MESSAGE)
        .list();
System.out.println(list.get(0)[0].getMessage().getNumber());
```

Comment: OP, it would at least be interesting to find out what object is at index 1. Your query clearly asks for just one item per row so my guess is that you have not posted the real query you are executing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That would probably be a string containing `v.message`. The OP should use `select v from Vote as v left join ...` if he just wants to get Vote objects in the list.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, that's the only explanation I could come up with and if it is correct, then your suggestion is clearly what OP should have done instead of this workaround. However, aren't the join semantics such that they just result in an eagerly loaded `message` field? Quote: `The associated objects are also not returned directly in the query results. Instead, they may be accessed via the parent object.` But this applies to *fetch* joins, so that may be the key difference. Hibernate's docs are generally quite hazy about these semantics, often it takes trial an error to second-guess them.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing it like this:

```
List<Object> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Vote as v left join v.message as m " +
                    "where m.question=:question and v.user=:user and v.voteType=:voteType")
            .setParameter("question", question)
            .setParameter("user", user)
            .setParameter("voteType", VoteType.MESSAGE)
            .list();
    System.out.println(((Vote) list.get(0)).getMessage().getNumber())
```

;

Comment: This is what OP *is* doing, only implicitly. It will fail with the same error.